# Unable to get gender from Facebook login via Parse for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-login

I followed [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial) tutorial from parse and configured my FB developer account along with needed package name and hash key as per their guidelines. In permissions, I have asked for user profile and email id so I should get their facebook ID, full name, gender and email id as per facebook [dcumentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#overview).

I am getting this JSON returned. Gender and email id are  not event featuring as key with null values. I have covered my FB id of course.
{"name":"Varun Agarwal","id":"11111111111111111"}

```
public void onLoginClick(View v) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);

    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
    // NOTE: for extended permissions, like "user_about_me", your app must be reviewed by the Facebook team
    // (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (user == null) {
          Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew()) {
          Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
          showUserDetailsActivity();
        } else {
          Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG, "User logged in through Facebook!");
          showUserDetailsActivity();
        }
      }
    });
  }

 private void makeMeRequest() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                if (jsonObject != null) {
                  JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                    Log.d("Data", jsonObject.toString());

                  try {
                    userProfile.put("facebookId", jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                    userProfile.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));

                    if (jsonObject.getString("gender") != null)
                      userProfile.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));

                    if (jsonObject.getString("email") != null)
                      userProfile.put("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));

                    // Save the user profile info in a user property
                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    currentUser.put("profile", userProfile);
                    currentUser.saveInBackground();

                    // Show the user info
                    updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                            "Error parsing returned user data. " + e);
                  }
                } else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                  switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) {
                    case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                      Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                              "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                      break;

                    case TRANSIENT:
                      Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                              "Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                      break;

                    case OTHER:
                      Log.d(IntegratingFacebookTutorialApplication.TAG,
                              "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                      break;
                  }
                }
              }
            });

    request.executeAsync();
  }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    makeMeRequest(); ---------> }
```

.Basically the name and some long fb id is all I am receiving. There is no gender or email appearing anywhere. The code above works if i comment out the parts related to gender and email since for gender==null to hold true, a key of "gender" must be declared as in {"gender":null} hence it is giving me issues until i comment out that part of the code.

Can someone suggest a solution please? This code, I have taken from their tutorial and read through the permissions given in FB documentation. Its strange that the name is coming but not the gender as both are in public profile information. I have checked my own FB account to make sure I have a gender set so that's not a problem.

Comment: You need to ask for the field first

Comment: if (jsonObject.getString("gender") != null)
                      userProfile.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender")); i am asking for it in this as well as in permissions

Comment: That is not asking for the field from Facebook. Read the changelog and declarative fields

Answer (score 0):

try this use graphResponse in place of jsonObject.

```
public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) 
{
    response.getJSONObject().getString("email")
    response.getJSONObject().getString("gender")
    response.getJSONObject().getString("id")
    response.getJSONObject().getString("name")
}
```

Comment: D/JSON MAINACTIVITY﹕ {"name":"Varun Agarwal","id":"10155851726080234"}

D/Graph Response﹕ {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"name":"Varun Agarwal","id":"10155851726080234"}, error: null}

This is what graphResponse and jsonObject contain, so in both of them the is being skipped.